# React: router props.match.params.id undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm working on a project that is not done by me.
I'm trying  to access the Id but what I'm  getting is undefined.

So there is array that contains routes :

```
const userRoutes = [
  .........................
  { path: "/edit-product/:productId", component: ManualProduct }
]
```

and it's beign used like this:

```
    import { userRoutes,...... } from "./routes/allRoutes";
const Authmiddleware = ({
    component: Component,
    layout: Layout
}) => (
    <Route
        render={props => {
            
            // here you can apply condition
            if (!localStorage.getItem("authUser")) {
                return (
                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
                );
            }
                
            return (
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </Layout>
            );
        }}
    />
);
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Router>
            <Switch>

      {userRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
        <Authmiddleware
          path={route.path}
          layout={Layout}
          component={route.component}
          key={idx}
        />
      ))}
......
......
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
```

And im getting productId undefined :

```
  console.log(props.match.params.productId);
```

Update:

i have tried doing this way but I'm getting redirected to the first root:

```
  <Router>
    <Switch>

      {userRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
        <Authmiddleware
          path={route.path}
          layout={Layout}
          component={route.component}
          key={idx}
        />
      ))}
      <Route
        path="/edit-product/:productId"
        exact
        component={ManualProduct}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: The `Authmiddleware` component is probably not forwarding the match property. Try to use your components with the HOC `withRouter`

Comment: just tried , isn't working with withRouter : export default withRouter(withNamespaces()(ManualProduct));

Comment: i have update my post maybe can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add ...rest

```
const Authmiddleware = ({
    component: Component,
    layout: Layout,
    ...rest ,  //add ...rest
}) => (
    <Route
       {...rest} // spread 
        render={props => {
            
            // here you can apply condition
            if (!localStorage.getItem("authUser")) {
                return (
                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
                );
            }
                
            return (
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </Layout>
            );
        }}
    />
);
```